# Developing with Python Class

Tags: python

Nothing scares me more than the Python Class concept; and recently I have been trying to use/create classes to understand their purpose, structure and features, etc. However, I am not clear about the concept of class and how to create them.

Please take a look at the following example:

```
class Prob(object):
    def __init__ (self,filename):
        self.file_contents = read_file(filename)
    def prob_build(self):
        self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(file_contents)

first_object = Prob(some_file)
alpha,beta, gamma = first_object.prob_build()
```

In this case, `read_file`, `build_problem` are custom functions that read data from a CSV file and build a PuLP-based linear problem, respectively. Now, my understanding is that when I initialize an object based on my `Prob` class, the file_contents are available for the class to use internally. In that case, how do I get the variables `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma`? For the current code, I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.` I have tested the functions and I know that they work without any error, which leaves me thinking that there is something wrong with the way I have defined the class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The syntax for defining methods requires that `self` be the first argument so that the method can access attributes of the instance.  In your example, you would need to do `build_problem(self.file_contents)`. This makes sense: You define `self.file_contents`, so you must access `self.file_contents`.  Your problem is arising because `prob_build` does not return anything, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: In addition to what @PatrickHaugh said, given your first statement, I consider you read over [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) documentation page.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, `build_problem(self.file_contents)` gives me `invalid syntax` error in Spyder, whereas  `build_problem(self)` produces an error message, `NameError: global name 'file_contents' is not defined`

Comment: That's odd.  I would expect to see that error for the code you posted, because it's using an identifier `file_contents` that hasn't been given a value.  Are you doing `file_contents = ...` somewhere outside your class?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, yes the error shows up in both cases. When I assign certain value to `file_contents` outside of the class, `first_object.prob_build()` works because it take the value of `file_contents` from the global namespace, I think. Also, I added a `return (self.problem, self.aux_vars)` to the 'prob_build' method, so the `TypeError` does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your `prob_build` method needs to `return` three values. You are currently not explicitly `return`ing anything so it implicitly returns the single value `None`, and Python tries to parse that into three values, and obviously failing.

This has nothing to do with the fact that this is a method of a class; functions return values regardless of how and where they are defined.

It's perfectly okay for functions to not return anything, of course; but then obviously it doesn't produce a result you can obtain with something like `variable = func()`

Comment: Why would it need to return values? Based on the naming, it should build a problem, not return values. If you want the internals of the problem, that would be a different function.

Comment: @JonKiparsky Thanks; attempted to clarify this. Better now?

Comment: Better. I think the OP would do well to spend a few happy hours curled up with a copy of Clean Code, but that's not your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing scares me more than the Python Class concept;

This is actually not a Python concept - classes exist in most object oriented languages.

> and recently I have been trying (...) to understand their purpose, structure and features, etc. However, I am not clear about the concept of class

Before we talk about classes, you have to understand objects. An object is a way to group together a state (a set of data) and a behavior (a set of functions acting on the state or according to the state). Now this is a bit of an abstract definition so let's see how it works with a simple example - a geometric point in a 2d space.

For the state part, a 2d point is defined by it's x and y coordinates. You can represent this with a `dict`:

```
my_point = {"x": 0, "y": 0}
```

Ok, fine but not very explicit and a bit error prone. We can start with a function that is responsible for creating a new point:

```
def new_point(x=0, y=0):
    return {"x": x, "y": y}

p1 = new_point()
p2 = new_point(42, 84)
```

Now we can build points without have to worry on the gory details. Ok, now let's a bit of behavior... A first useful function would be to check whether two points are equal (let's say they are equal if they have the same coordinates):

```
def points_are_equal(p1, p2):
    return p1["x"] == p2["x"] and p1["y"] == p2["y"]
```

You can see that this behavior depends on both points states.

We could also want to move a point along the horizontal axis:

```
def move_x(p, distance):
    p["x"] += distance
```

or along the vertical axis:

```
def move_y(p, distance):
    p["y"] += distance
```

or both at the same time:

```
def move_by(p, x_distance, y_distance):
    move_x(p, x_distance)
    move_y(p, y_distance)
```

Notice that here, the behavior is to change the point's state.

And of course we want to have a way to get the point's x or y coordinates:

```
 def get_x(p):
     return p["x"]

 def get_y(p)
     return p["y"]
```

What we've built here is what is known as an "abstract data type": instead of manually building a dict, manually comparing two dicts,  manually updating our dict and manually checking it's state, we have defined a set a function to do all this, more or less hiding the internal representation.

> and how to create them.

A class is, mostly, another way to do the same thing, but with a lot of other goodness. Let's rewrite our "point" datatype as a Python class:

```
class Point(object):
    # this is the function that creates a new point
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # equality test:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    # move
    def move_x(self, distance):
        self.x += distance

    def move_y(self, distance):
        self.y += distance

    def move_by(self, x_distance, y_distance):
        self.move_x(x_distance)
        self.move_y(y_distance)
```

And we don't actually need to write `get_x()` nor `get_y()`, we can directly access x and y:

```
p = Point(2, 5)
print(p.x)
print(p.y)

p.move_by(3, 1)
print(p.x)
print(p.y)

p2 = Point(p.x, p.y)
print(p == p2) # => True
p2.move_x(3)
print(p == p2) # => False
```

Actually, behind the hood, our `p` object *is* a dict:

```
print(p.__dict__)
```

Other OOPLs might use other ways to store an object's state (structs for C-like languages for example), but in Python an object is actually mainly a dict. Well, a dict plus a class:

```
print(p.__class__)
```

and a set of "attribute lookup rules" (provided by the base class `object`) that will first lookup attributes on the object's `__dict__` then on the object's class (which is how `p.move_x(42)` is actually interpreted as `Point.move_x(p, 42)`.

Classes and objects provide a lot of other goodies (inheritance etc), but basically they are just this: a dict (which stores the state) and a class (which stores the behavior).

Now for your example:

> my understanding is that when I initialize an object based on my Prob class, the file_contents are available for the class to use internally

`file_contents` is available for the *instance* - and the class functions can access it *on the current instance* - which is the `self` parameter. IOW, your `build_prob` function should use `self.file_contents`:

```
def prob_build(self):
    self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(self.file_contents)
```

Then you can access the `problem` and `aux_vars` on your instance:

```
first_object = Prob(some_file)
first_object.prob_build() 
print(first_object.problem)
print(first_object.aux_vars)
```

Just note that the `problem` and `aux_vars` attributes only exist after you called `prob_build`. This is considered as bad practice, since you can get an  `AttributeError` :

```
first_object = Prob(some_file)
# Doesn't work !!!
print(first_object.problem)
```

A first step to fix this would be to initialize those attributes in the `__init__` method (yes, that's why it's called "**init**"):

```
class Prob(object):
    def __init__ (self,filename):
        self.file_contents = read_file(filename)
        self.problem = None
        self.aux_vars = None

    def prob_build(self):
        self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(self.file_contents)
```

but that's hardly better - you still need to call `yourobj.prob_build()` to have a *usable* state. The obvious fix here is to do **all** the initialization in the initializer and get rid of `prob_build`:

```
class Prob(object):
    def __init__ (self,filename):
        self.file_contents = read_file(filename)
        self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(self.file_contents)
```

but then you can ask yourself: what's the point of this class if it has no behavior, and all you do is:

```
 prob = Prob("path/to/file.csv")
 prob, aux_vars = prob.problem, prob.aux_vars
 result = do_something_with(prob, aux_vars)
```

You could as well replace it with a simple function:

```
def build_problem_from_file(path):
    return build_problem(read_file(path))

 prob, aux_vars = build_problem_from_file(...)
 result = do_something_with(prob, aux_vars)
```

As a general rule, if your class as either no state or no behavior, chances are you don't need a class. There are exceptions to this rule of course but this is still a good guideline. In your case, the hypothetical `do_something_with(prob, aux_vars)` might be a method too:

```
class Prob(object):
    def __init__ (self,filename):
        self.file_contents = read_file(filename)
        self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(self.file_contents)

     def do_something(self):
         # some computations here using self.problem and self.aux_vars
         return result  

 prob = Prob("path/to/file.csv")
 result = prob.do_something()
```

but if that's the only behavior, you still don't need a class:

```
def build_problem_from_file(path):
    return build_problem(read_file(path))

 def resolve_problem_from_file(path):
     prob, aux_vars = build_problem_from_file(...)
     return do_something_with(prob, aux_vars)

 result = resolve_problem_from_file(...)
```

So to make a long story short: ask yourself if and why you want a class. OOP is a good solution for some problems but is not the solution to all problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed and simple explanation. Very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW I edited my answer with some more considerations, which may or not apply to your concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to normal `functions`, class `methods` need to return something if you want the results! In your code, `prob_build` doesn't return anything! So, it should be something like this:

```
def prob_build(self):
    self.problem, self.aux_vars = build_problem(file_contents)
    return (self.problem, self.aux_vars)
```

Note that in this case, it returns two arguments. You should be more specific on what `alpha`, `beta`, and `gamma` are!

Answer (score 0):

Your class function prob_build() does not return anything. It only sets variables internal to the class.